# Cannot resolve unit name delphi xe4 with platform not same windows platform 64 bit

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe4

I have a problem using Delphi XE4.  After creating a FireMonkey mobile project, there are estimated errors: `"cannot resolve unit name"`, for all units I am using. I am on Windows 7 64-bit running the the latest version update of Delphi XE4.

When I create an application form VCL - Delphi platform with Windows 32 and I have the same problem after the addition of the Windows 64 platform and activated, no errors were found.

Comment: I edited your question but I have not been able to make sense of the second paragraph.  Please do your best to provide clarification.  Also: what do you mean by "estimated errors"?

Comment: Your title needs clarification as well, but since I don't understand the problem, I have not been able to suggest an edit for the title.

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE

Answer (score 2):

Go into the Project Options and make sure the correct **Unit Scope Names** are listed for the units you want to use (System, Vcl, Fmx, Winapi, etc). If they are, then make sure the search paths are configured correctly.